# Library or API that will compare two text file and generate a difference text file in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy Script

Is there any Library or API that will compare two text file and generate a difference text file automatically.

Description:

I have on text file "old.txt" having some data. After I am changing the content of the "old.txt" like inserting one line, deleting one line and updating some line.

Can any one please tell is there any library that can compare and give the output as giving by the "TortiosUdiff" .patch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use any Java library from your Groovy script. [Here's one](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/) that appears to do what you need.